# How to config Flex Mojos Unit test by maven

Tags: maven, maven-2, flex4.5, maven-plugin, pom.xml

Like java I would like to perform unit test in maven flex mojo. but unable to perform unit test. Here is the pom file for your observation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.formativesoft.flex</groupId>
  <artifactId>rdpair</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <packaging>swf</packaging>

  <name>rdpair Flex</name>  
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
      <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.1.21328</version>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.flexunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>flexunit</artifactId>
      <version>0.85</version>
      <type>swc</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/flex</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
        <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0-RC2</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

which properties/plugins/dependency is missing for performing maven unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare which files contains the tests:

```
<includeTestFiles>
    <includeTestFile>*Test.as</includeTestFile>
</includeTestFiles>
```

And also specify the path to the flash player (move that in your settings.xml)

```
<properties>
    <flex.flashplayer.url>C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\player\win\11.1\FlashPlayerDebugger.exe</flex.flashplayer.url>
</properties>
```